# How can I prove the ill-effects of binning/discretization?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binning

There is a binary classification model built where there is grouping of continuous variables into arbitrary ranges which I am told is to include a good number of outliers in the data set. How do I prove the ill-effects of  binning to non-technical colleagues ? Preferably through some plots and graphs to show that it impacts classification (without having to re-build the model)

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/categorizing-continuous-variables/3402

Comment: This discusses binning's issues in a predictive modeling context: http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2017/08/04/basis-expansions.html